# What is the meaning of “erst vor knapp” in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

The sentence:

> Es lag etwas Verwirrendes im Ausdruck ihrer grünblauen Augen, wenn sie verliebt zu ihrem Freund aufblickte, der sie erst vor knapp einer halben Stunde unvermittelt gefragt hatte: ...

I can’t seem to make sense of “erst vor knapp”

Comment: It seems you also can't make sense of the shift keys on your keyboard. They can be used to type uppercase letters (which caused six orthographic errors in your German quote). I corrected this for you.

Comment: From your recent posts, it seems you are reading C. C. Bergius' "Das Medallion"? Feel free to give the source of the text you are quoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole expression you should be looking at, is: "erst vor knapp einer halben Stunde"

This means, that he asked her *nearly half an hour ago* or *just under half an hour ago*, but not exactly thirty minutes ago.

A similiar expression you might be coming across is "vor gut einer halben Stunde", which means something happened slightly over half an hour ago.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. Could you also explain the meaning of vor in this context? I kind of want to say it roughly translates to “previously ” in this particular context, does that sound right?

Comment: In this case "vor" simply can be translated as "ago".

Answer (score 2):

Here, in this context:

- erst = just
- vor = ago
- knapp = almost
- einer = a(n)
- halben = half
- Stunde = hour

I don't know, if this is good English, but I would translate this phrase this way:

> just almost half an hour ago

The whole quote:

> There was something confusing in the expression of her green-blue eyes when she looked up in love to her boyfriend, who had asked her just almost half an hour ago: ...